# Python create multiple log files

Tags: python, multithreading, logging, batch-processing

I am using batch processing and call below function parallelly. I need to create new log file for each process

Below is sample code

import logging

def processDocument(inputfilename):
logfile=inputfilename+'.log'

```
logging.basicConfig( 
filename=logfile, 
level=logging.INFO)

//performing some function

logging.info("process completed for file")
logging.shutdown()
```

It is creating log file. But when I pass this function in batch for calling 20 times. Only 16 log files are getting created.

Answer (score 0):

These issue can happen with threads race conditions.

If the document processing is independent from each other, I would suggest to use `multiprocessing` via the high level class `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`.

If you want to stick to threads because the document processing is more I/O bound, there is `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`, which provides the same interface but with threads.

Last but not least, configure properly your `logging` like this toy example (which uses standard `threading` library):

```py
import logging
from sys import stdout
import time 
import threading

def processDocument(inputfilename:str):
    logfile = inputfilename + '.log'
    this_thread = threading.current_thread().name

    this_thread_logger = logging.getLogger(this_thread)

    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename=logfile)
    out_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stdout)

    file_handler.level = logging.INFO
    out_handler.level = logging.INFO

    this_thread_logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    this_thread_logger.addHandler(out_handler)

    this_thread_logger.info(f'Processing {inputfilename} from {this_thread}...')
    time.sleep(1) # processing
    this_thread_logger.info(f'Processing {inputfilename} from {this_thread}... Done')
    

def main():
    filenames = ['hello', 'hello2', 'hello3']

    threads = [threading.Thread(target=processDocument, args=(name,)) for name in filenames]
    
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    logging.shutdown()

main()
```